# How to document a preprocessor definition dependent typedef using Doxygen?

Tags: c, doxygen

Is it possible to document a typedef that depending on a preprocessor define has different types in a way that displays both alternatives in html output using Doxygen?

The code I'd like to document:

```
/**
 * \file
 */

#ifdef _WIN32
/**
 * Documentation for Windows goes here...
 */
typedef wchar_t MyChar;
#else
/**
 * Documentation for Non-Windows goes here...
 */
typedef char MyChar;
#endif
```

I've tested several preprocessor-related settings, but I could only change the typedef displayed in the html output or merge the documentation. I even managed to have one typedef show up in the overview section of the file and the other one in the detailed description. However I wasn't able to make both alternatives show up simultaneously.

I managed to produce the following 2 alternatives:

```
----------------------------------------------
typedef wchar_t   | MyChar   | ....
----------------------------------------------
```

```
----------------------------------------------
typedef char      | MyChar   | ....
----------------------------------------------
```

But not something like this

```
----------------------------------------------
typedef wchar_t   | MyChar   | ....
----------------------------------------------
typedef char      | MyChar   | ....
----------------------------------------------
```

---

Note: I don't mind modifying the source code as long as

- In the documentation both alternatives are reasonably documented in the Doxygen output; both `wchar_t` and `char` need to be displayed in the `typedef ...` part
- The compiler produces the same result for the modified and the current version of the file
- IDE autocompletion, in particular Visual Studio 2019's IntelliSense, still displays reasonable tooltips (optional)

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party but...

---

If you set [`ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES`](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_enable_preprocessing) in your `Doxyfile` and then also set [`PREDEFINED = DOXYGEN`](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_predefined), you can then do something like this:

```cpp
#if defined(DOXYGEN)
    /// @brief On Windows
    typedef wchar_t MyChar;

    /// @brief On other systems
    typedef char MyChar;
#else
    #if defined(_WIN32)
        typedef wchar_t MyChar;
    #else
        typedef char MyChar;
    #endif
#endif
```

So the compiler ends up seeing and selecting only one definition, but Doxygen sees both definitions and adds them both to the output.

You can reduce the amount of duplication at the cost of reducing the readability:

```cpp
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(DOXYGEN)
    /// @brief On Windows
    typedef wchar_t MyChar;
#endif

#if !defined(_WIN32) || defined(DOXYGEN)
    /// @brief On other systems
    typedef char MyChar;
#endif
```

That `!` is much more subtle compared to some nice big `#else`s, but it does at least mean that you won't accidentally change the definition in the main code and then forget to change the corresponding documentation.

Though if you need to support a lot of different operating systems then this could easily turn into a long list of overly complex conditions.

---

Theoretically there should also be a way to achieve this using the [`\typedef`](https://doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdtypedef) command as a form of explicit documentation, but when I attempted it I couldn't get it to work.

---

Lastly, there's the possibility that setting `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = NO` would actually cause Doxygen to read:

```cpp
#if defined(_WIN32)
    /// @brief On Windows
    typedef wchar_t MyChar;
#else
    /// @brief On other systems
    typedef char MyChar;
#endif
```

As if it were:

```cpp
/// @brief On Windows
typedef wchar_t MyChar;

/// @brief On other systems
typedef char MyChar;
```

But at the moment, that is an untested theory.

---

Note that any of these solutions may end up breaking reference links because you're effectively defining the same symbol twice when Doxygen is expecting every symbol to be unique.

Comment: This seems to add the descriptions of both typedefs to the documentation of the typedef. However it doesn't result in both possible types being displayed. As a result you probably don't risk breaking references, but you also don't get the result I was looking for using this approach...

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, just more a question / suggestion whether the following would be acceptable:

```
/** \cond */
#ifdef _WIN32
#define used_type wchar_t
#else
#define used_type char
#endif
/** \endcond */
/**
 * Documentation for Windows goes here...
 *
 * Documentation for Non-Windows goes here...
 */
typedef used_type MyChar;
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This may be one step to a possible solution. I'd need to add documentation to the macro mentioning both alternatives. However a solution where I can see the types in the summary (excluding the "brief" part) would be preferrable.